# Why does ofstream work here, but not fstream?

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to understand a difference between `std::ofstream` and `std::fstream`. I have this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    //create an output stream to write to the file
    //append the new lines to the end of the file
    ofstream myfileI ("input.txt", ios::app);
    
    
    if (myfileI.is_open())
    {

        myfileI << "\nI am adding a line.\n";
        cout << myfileI.fail() << "\n";
        myfileI << "I am adding another line.\n";
        cout << myfileI.fail() << "\n";

        myfileI.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file for writing";
```

The fail bits return 0, so it is writing.

But the fail bits return 1 when I use the exact same code but instead use `fstream` instead of `ofstream`.

input.txt is just this:

```
Read and write to this file. 

What am I doing here?

This is not a good example of a file
```

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/991c6cbf2bc23a17)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the *failing* program instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no *practical* difference between the two cases you describe.

The ONLY *technical* difference is that `ofstream` always has the `ios::out` flag enabled, which will be added to any flags you specify. Whereas `fstream` has the `ios::in` and `ios::out` flags enabled *by default*, but will be overriden by any flags you specify.

So, in the `ofstream` case you are opening the file in `ios::out | ios::app` mode, whereas in the `fstream` case you are opening the file in just `ios::app` mode.

But, both streams delegate to [`std::filebuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf), and according to [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) for `std::filebuf::open()`, both `out|app` and `app` modes act the exact same way - as if `fopen(filename, "a")` were used, thus they will both "Append to file" if the file exists, and "Create new" if the file does not exist.

[image]

Comment: When I changed the `ofstream` line to `fstream myfileI ("input.txt", ios::app|ios::out)`, instead of `fstream myfileI ("input.txt", ios::app)`, it correctly wrote to the file.